# Handling JSON string in python

Tags: python, json

i have an string  for example

```
var = "{"name":"angelo","apellido":"enriquez"}"
```

but when doing the following function I get an error

```
data = json.loads(var)
```

> Error : No JSON object could be decoded
>   Any help?

Comment: please select an answer if this helped

Answer (score 1):

Replace your var with :

```
var = '{"name":"angelo","apellido":"enriquez"}'
```

i.e put the content inside {} within single quotes (') instead of double .

Hope that helps .

Comment: YEAH , IT WORKS  THNKS

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not writing good json in javascript, replace inner " double quotes with single ' quotes.

```
var MyJSVar = {'hello':'bra'}
```

If string

```
var MyJSVar = "{'hello':'bra'}"
```

Comment: is beacause i'm reading from a file .. and returns me a str i guess that it is between " ...."

Comment: i use Readlines and this iterate into a loop